# Why is rightBarButtonItem crashing?

Tags: iphone

Why do I get a crash `"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]"` after setting `rightBarButtonItem`?

In my app, I have three buttons on the right hand side, one of which should alternate with the `systemEditButton`. So I set the buttons up with`rightBarButtonItems` (note the "s") and then change the right-hand one using rightBarButtonItem when appropriate.

With 5.0, Apple lets you set multiple items in the `leftBarButtonItems` and `rightBarButtonItems` of a `NavigationBar`.  It also says you can change the outer one with `leftBarButtonItem` and `rightBarButtonItem` respectively ("The first item in the array can also be set using the `rightBarButtonItem` property").

Works fine the first time, but then it crashes when I put back the original button.  Even worse, it doesn't object when I set it, it crashes later during the animation of `UINavigationBar layoutSubViews`.  Checking `rightBarButtonItems` after setting `rightBarButtonItems` shows it correctly updated the array, but it crashes during layout.

Comment: It would be better to state this as a question (“Why am I getting this exception...”) and then post an answer yourself.  It's fine to accept your own answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks. I was not clear of the Jeopardy-like nature of posting!

Comment: Thanks for the reminder.  They make one wait two days for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've confirmed this with a test program (see below), and submitted a bug-report to Apple.  The workaround is to read the Items array and hand it back a new one with the zeroth element updated.

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  testBarButton
//
//  Created by Hugh Mackworth on 3/4/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 PineTree Software. All rights reserved.
//
#import "ViewController.h"
//#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
//
//@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
//    
//@private
//    UIBarButtonItem * itemA;
//}
//
//@property (strong, nonatomic) UIBarButtonItem * itemA;
//
//@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize itemA;  //@property (strong, nonatomic) UIBarButtonItem * itemA;

-(void) reportButtons {
    NSLog (@"buttons:  %@",self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems);
}

-(void) itemA:(id) sender {
    NSLog(@"itemA hit");
   [self reportButtons];
}

-(void) itemB:(id) sender {
    NSLog(@"itemB hit");
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.itemA;
    [self reportButtons];
}

-(void) itemC:(id) sender {
    NSLog(@"itemC hit");
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    [self reportButtons];
}

-(void) loadView {
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.itemA = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Alternative Edit",@"")
                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                             target:self
                                                             action:@selector(itemA:)]; 
    UIBarButtonItem *itemB = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"B-Hit Second",@"")
                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                             target:self
                                                             action:@selector(itemB:)]; //fix with itemB2:
    UIBarButtonItem *itemC = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"C-Hit First",@"")
                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                             target:self
                                                             action:@selector(itemC:)]; //fix with itemC2:
    NSArray *rightItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                           self.itemA,
                           itemB,
                           itemC,
                           nil];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = rightItems;
    [self reportButtons];                       

}

-(void) swapRightItem: (UIBarButtonItem *) newRightItem {
    NSMutableArray * newRightItems = [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems mutableCopy];
    [newRightItems replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject: newRightItem];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = newRightItems;
    [self reportButtons];
}

-(void) itemB2:(id) sender {
    NSLog(@"itemB2 hit");
    [self swapRightItem:self.itemA];
}

-(void) itemC2:(id) sender {
    NSLog(@"itemC2 hit");
    [self swapRightItem:self.editButtonItem];
}

@end

//APP DELEGATE:
/*
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController * viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *watchNavController= [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController ];

    self.window.rootViewController = watchNavController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
*/
```